Prove a lower bound on eigenvalues of a class of matrices
I am not sure if this is trivial or not. Let $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be real and symmetric, with the property that
$$
\mathbf{A}_{ii} = 1, \quad \mathbf{A}_{ij} \in [0,1], \quad i,j \in \{1,\dots,n\}.
$$
Let $t \in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfy $t_i > 0$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ and $\sum_{j=1}^n t_j = 1$.
Now suppose we define $\mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ as
$$
\mathbf{B}_{ii} := \frac{\mathbf{A}_{ii}}{t_i}, \quad \mathbf{B}_{ij} := \mathbf{A}_{ij}\quad i,j=1,\dots,n\; j \neq i
$$
In other words, we pointwise rescale the diagonal of $\mathbf{A}$ by a vector lying on the probability simplex. From extensive numerical tests it seems to be a universal feature that the lowest eigenvalue of $\mathbf{B}$ is greater than (or equal?) 1. Can that be proven? I only have a partial argument:

If the weights are uniform, $t_i = \frac{1}{n}$, then Gershgorin circle theorem seems to guarantee that all eigenvalues are greater than or equal to 1.
We can write
$$
\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{A} + \underbrace{\mathbf{B} - \mathbf{A}}_{=:\mathbf C} 
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{C} = {\rm diag}\left(\left\{\frac{1}{t_i}-1\right\}_{i=1,\dots,n}\right) = {\rm diag}\left(\left\{\frac{1-t_i}{t_i}\right\}_{i=1,\dots,n}\right)
$$
The trace of $\mathbf{A}$ is equal to $n$, so we seem to get a general equality
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i = n + \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1-t_i}{t_i} \text{ and equivalently } \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{t_i},
$$
where $\lambda_i$ is the ith eigenvalue of $\mathbf{B}$.
If the smallest entry $t_i$ is really tiny, then the largest eigenvalue of $\mathbf{B}$ will be approximately equal to $\frac{1}{t_i}$. This "essentially" establishes the result when $t_i \approx 1$ (since then all other ones are tiny).

Am I missing something obvious to finish off the argument? :)

Let $D$ be a diagonal matrix with $d_{i,i}:= t_i$.  The goal is to prove $B-I\succeq \mathbf 0$
First consider the eigenvalues of $\big(B-I\big)D$.  This matrix has $1-t_i$ on the $i$th diagonal component and $a_{i,j}\cdot t_j\geq 0 $ on the off diagonals.
$\sum_{j\neq i} \vert a_{i,j}\cdot t_j\vert =\sum_{j\neq i} a_{i,j}\cdot t_j \leq \sum_{j\neq i} t_j = 1-t_i $
By Gerschgorin Discs all eigenvalues of $\big(B-I\big)D$ have real component $\geq 0$. By similarity:
$\implies D^\frac{1}{2}\Big(\big(B-I\big)D\Big)D^\frac{-1}{2}=D^\frac{1}{2}\big(B-I\big)D^\frac{1}{2}\succeq \mathbf 0\implies \big(B-I\big)\succeq \mathbf 0$ by congruence

Beautiful, thank you very much!
